# R Repeat function from first subvector of vector until total vector length reached

Tags: r

I have a vector epsilon of length N. I am applying the function **bw.CDF.pi(x, pilot="UCV")** from the **sROC** package to compute bandwidths for cdf Kernel estimation.

My goal is to repeat this bandwidth function for every subvector from epsilon from the beginning value on. Stated otherwise, I would like to apply this function for the first value in epsilon, then for the first two values in epsilon, then for the first three values in epsilon, continiuing until the function is applied fot the total vector epsilon. Finally i want to have then N values for the bandwidth.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Hi! Have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example. Your question needs to have reproducible data as well as an expected output.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you need a vector of 2 elements for the function `bw.CDF.pi` to run. If you want to run it for the first 2 elemts of a vector, then the first 3, etc, you can do the following. Note that the data example is the one in the help page for the function.

```
library(sROC)

set.seed(100)
n <- 200
x <- c(rnorm(n/2, mean=-2, sd=1), rnorm(n/2, mean=3, sd=0.8))

lapply(seq_along(x)[-1], function(m) bw.CDF.pi(x[seq_len(m)], pilot="UCV"))
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that was helpful!